# how to remove last 3 letters from string including spaces in r

Tags: r

I have following dataframe in r

```
  Date                    Count   
  2016-12-30 17:25:00      34
  2016-12-04 10:25:00      31
```

I want to change the format to following and want to remove seconds from Date

Desired Dataframe would be

```
  Date                 Count
  30-12-2016 17:25     34
  04-12-2016 10:25     31
```

I am doing following but because of space inbetween date it is returning me wrong output

```
 substr(df$Date,1,nchar(df$Date)-3)
```

How can I do it in R?

Comment: I feel that you should be using a function which accepts a full timestamp rather than lopping off numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We convert it to `POSIXct` and then do the `format`

```
df1$Date <- format(as.POSIXct(df1$Date), "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M")
df1$Date
#[1] "30-12-2016 17:25" "04-12-2016 10:25"
```

Comment: That works, but what if I want to trim last 3 letters in above case which includes spaces,how can we do it?

Comment: @Neil If the format is not an issue, then use `substr` i.e. `substring(trimws(df1$Date), 1, nchar(df1$Date)-3)`